# OAuth2.0 and OpenID Connect Confusing

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am confused about the use of OAuth 2.0 as an Authorization method and OpenID Connect as an Authentication method.

Based on my knowledge **OAuth 2.0** is only an Authorization method. In other words, this is the process to request an ACCESS_TOKEN and RECEIVE this ACCESS_TOKEN, like depicted in the image below in yellow ellipse: (simplified)

[image]

Before an OAuth 2.0 Client retrieves an ACCESS_TOKEN from an Authorization Server this Server should verify if the User allows it and this is an Authentication Process that OAuth 2.0 does not care about.

When OpenID Connect is included in the mix it allows for an Authentication Method as well, but in my knowledge OpenID Connect just adds a "Claim" in the JWT Token that holds information about user that is using the service, like: email, name and others.

My questions are:

1. Why not ignore OpenID Connect and just add more "claims" in OAuth
   2.0 to get information about users?
2. Is my description of the flows correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@sdoxee answers explains thing correctly. But I am adding bit more information for OP's understanding.

These days many identity providers (eg:- Azure AD) issue JWT based access tokens. These JWT access tokens do contain claims about end user as well as JWT related validation details (eg:- Token expiration). Here is the link for Azure AD [OAuth 2 success response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1) which highlights access token to be a JWT. Also, see [JWT claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#jwt-token-claims) to see how they explain the claims. Samples are given below,

> f**amily_name** : User’s last name or surname. The application can display this value.
>
> **given_name** :  User’s first name. The application can display this value.

One could think of building authentication on claims present in access token, but this is not sticking with protocol. And mostly claims and user information will be implementer specific. Also, by protocol definition, these two tokens (id and access) have two different audiences.

- ID token is for client, for validation and for authentication.
- Access token is for OAuth 2 protected endpoint.

Again, as @sdoxee highlight, use the correct protocol at correct place. Having claims in access token does not necessarily mean you should use them for authentication.

Comment: When user try to share a content from a third site to Facebook a login page is showed before Grant access, this is not authentication process ? This is made with Oauth?

Comment: This is the authentication process between resource owner and the authorization server. The Facebook user is the resource owner and Facebook is the authorization server here. Resource is resource owner's account. And this is OAuth 2.0 thing. And it is not authentication for client application(ex:- Third site which share content)

Comment: Thanks , now makes senses

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if your method will work or not but you're totally free to roll your own authentication. After all, that's what Facebook, GitHub and many others did by customizing oauth2. There ended up being so many oauth2 "authentication" methods that it was never plug and play if you wanted to change your provider. I believe that's why OpenID connect was introduced--a common way of connecting and reasoning about authentication while building on the established oauth2 pattern for authorization. Use OpenID connect or don't...but if you don't you'll be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 7):

OpenID Connect does not merely "add a claim in JWT Token" but:

1. it introduces a completely new token (`id_token`) with radically different
   semantics than the OAuth 2.0 `access_token` and a standardized format that is understood by the Client as opposed to the `access_token` which is opaque to the Client
2. it "twists" the role of the Client, now becoming the "audience" (or: intended recipient) of a token (i.e. the `id_token`) whilst the audience of the `access_token` is still a remote entity (aka. Resource Server) and the Client is only the "presenter" of the latter

The 2nd item is the primary source of confusion between OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect.